# Why does my Jetpack Compose horizontalPager show the same image on all pages despite passing a list of different image URIs from Firebase storage

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I’m working on creating an image slider using Jetpack Compose’s horizontalPager. My goal is to display a series of images fetched from Firebase storage. However, despite passing a list of different image URIs, the horizontalPager consistently shows the same image on all pages. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
@Composable
fun ImageSlider(imageUriList: List<Uri>){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    ) {
        val pageCount = imageUriList.size
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
            pageCount = { pageCount },
        )
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            Log.d("page","$it")
            AsyncImage(model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(imageUriList[it])
                .build(),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
                contentDescription =""
            )

        }
        Row(
            Modifier
                .height(50.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            repeat(pageCount) { iteration ->
                val color = if (pagerState.currentPage == iteration) Color.DarkGray else Color.LightGray
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .background(color, CircleShape)
                        .size(10.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I used